# How to fix centerOffset on KineticJs on Rotation

Tags: kineticjs

Im having trouble with centerOffset on KineticJs, when I rotate the object (a rectangle) the center gets way off and I cant find a way to correct it.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the rotation offset during the object instantiation. So, to make the rotation point in the center of the object, divide height and width by 2 :

```
 var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: 100,
      height: 50,
      fill: "#ff0000",
      offset: [50, 25]
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, but lets say im dragging that object and it gets rotated (when it's at 10% distance of another object) then the center seems to get lost and the product ends pixels away from the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me (offsets a group element):

```
your_group_element.offset( { x: 50, y: 50 } );
```